# How to float a div on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to float 2 divs when I am scrolling but is going to show only the right div on top of left one. Any idea how to fix this?

**HTML**

```
<body>
        <div id="scroller-left">Some controls left</div>
        <div id="scroller-right">Some controls right</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
            height:2000px;
            width: 100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #scroller-left{
            float: left;
            background:#CCC;
        }
        #scroller-right{
            float: right;
            background:#CCC;
        }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).load(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop()>10){
                    $('#scroller-left').css('position', 'fixed');
                    $('#scroller-left').css('top', 0);
                    $('#scroller-right').css('position', 'fixed');
                    $('#scroller-right').css('top', 0);
                } else {
                    $('#scroller-left').css('position', 'relative');
                    $('#scroller-left').css('top', 0);
                    $('#scroller-right').css('position', 'relative');
                    $('#scroller-right').css('top', 0);
                }
            });
        });
```

**Jsfiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/q0fa81hf

thank you.

Comment: The mechanism that doesn't let you post a jsfiddle-link without code is there for a reason. Please keep example code to your question **in your question**. It's fine to use jsfiddle, but not like this. It's very inconventient. I had to mark, copy, open a new tab and paste to see your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, there is no need for JS solution in this case. My solution CSS only:

```
body {
    height:2000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#scroller-left{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    background:#CCC;
}

#scroller-right{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    background:#CCC;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0fa81hf/1/)

Comment: This is the good solution. Put floats to achieve fixed position and control it by javascript is so weird....